# TLS handshake failure

Tags: security, ssl, istio

We have an ODBC Driver trying to connect through TLS , but fails.
We tested using openssl with the following command and worked fine:

> openssl s_client -connect xxx.com:31020

the server accepts TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.3 (downgraded just for debugging)

While Trying to connect , here is the wireshark handshake capture flow:

[image]

and also while expanding the client hello TLS, this is what we have :

[image]

Any idea what's causing the handshake not to start properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are using ISTIO as Ingress Gateway with Kubernetes, the issue is related to ISTIO gateway config.
We simply had to replace the matching host to '*' in ISTIO gateway config